# window.opener reference lost in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Consider the following case:

- Step 1: Website A opens Website B in a new tab (At this point Website B has its opener window reference i.e Website A window object in window.opener).
- Step 2: Website B redirects to Website C (We have window.opener referencing Website A window here too).
- Step 3: Then Website C performs some authentication and redirects back to Website B.
  At this step 3 the window.opener has the reference of the current window object i.e window object of Website B itself (window.opener === window) and we’ve lost reference to the original opener (i.e Website A window object). We need the window.opener object for communicating with Website A using postMessage.

[Visual reperesentation of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl4N2.png)

Note: We don’t have control over Website C and can’t control how they’re redirecting back to Website B.
Also this is happening only on Firefox/Safari. On Chrome we're able to get the original opener reference after redirections.

In case Website C is redirecting with rel=noopener the window.opener should be null ([Reference from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener)). I’m not able to understand in which case the window.opener can be the current window object and why it is happening on Firefox/Safari but not on Chrome? And is there anything we can do anywhere except Website C to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in firefox and Safari, window.opener can be current window when you add target `_self`. If you do `window.open('someurl', '_self')` then window.opener will be current window and will open in same tab instead of a new tab. This only happens in safari and firefox(from what i have observed). All chromium based browsers don't change the original window opener in any case.

I don't know the exact reason why safari and firefox handles it this way I tried to find the reason but can't find it.

I faced this issue once and the solution which we did was to ask website C to use either `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href` to redirect back to website B so they open website b in same tab.